# Why does recursive grep show 'No such file or directory' errors?

Tags: grep, symlink

I'm grepping a local svn directory. When I run `grep -r "pattern" .` I get some errors such as

> grep: ./Data/test: No such file or directory

Who asked `grep` to look for non-existent files?

---

```
>grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.10

>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

Comment: What is `./Data/test`? grep can spit out this type of error when it encounters a symbolic link that points to a non-existent file.

Comment: @j.w.r seems like it's a broken symbolic link (as per file command).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default, grep would not ignore non-existent or unreadable files.  You need to supply the `-s` or `--no-messages` option in order to do so.  Quoting from `man grep`:

> ```
>    -s, --no-messages
>           Suppress  error  messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
>           Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not
>           conform to POSIX, because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved
>           like GNU grep's -q option.  USG-style grep also  lacked  -q  but
>           its  -s  option  behaved  like GNU grep.  Portable shell scripts
>           should avoid both -q and -s and  should  redirect  standard  and
>           error output to /dev/null instead.  (-s is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: An example of non-existent would be a broken symlink.  Unreadable, as the word suggests, refers to the files for which the current user doesn't have read permissions.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution once grep doesn't work with `2>/dev/null`