# Best way to search through the source code of all the gems for a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I'm getting a warning on my console that i'd like to resolve. The problem is that i'm not sure which gem is causing this warning. What is the best way to search through the source for all the gems for a specific project.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do the following:

```
cd `bundle show rails` # Go to the directory having rails gem content
cd ..                  # Go one level up to the folder having all gems
grep -ir escape_javascript *  # search for the required text in all files
> actionview-4.1.6/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:      def escape_javascript(javascript)
> actionview-4.1.6/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:      alias_method :j, :escape_javascript
```

**EDIT**: The answer below by jrochkind is the correct answer; my answer is incorrect as it searches through all the gems installed in the system.

Comment: `grep -ir escape_javascript *`
`grep: *: No such file or directory`

Comment: `No such file or directory` would be because of some unreadable/nonexistent files; fixed by passing `-s` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16297914/429758 ; `grep -isr escape_javascript *` . The bundle folder shouldn't have this problem though as it does not have any symlinks.

Comment: It works Prakash. But my rails gem directory is empty. Do you know why?

Comment: rails gem directory should have just the guides and README.md. Rest of the code is bundled in other gems. Not sure what the issue is if the folder is totally empty.

Comment: Here is a better way to do the same: http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2013/03/15/searching-through-your-bundled-gems/

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer will search through *all* gems installed on your system, possibly including ones that aren't actually dependencies.

To search *only* through actual dependencies of your app, not just any installed gem, from the app root dir:

```
grep -r "escape_javascript" $(bundle show --paths) .
```

The `.` on the end will make sure to search your actual app too, not *only* it's dependencies. If that's what you want.

From http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/bundle-grep-and-rails-applications/68

Comment: Using https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher :

`ag i_search_for_escape_javascript --ruby \`bundle show --paths\``