# Understanding escaped parentheses in find

Tags: bash, shell, find, quoting

I've cobbled together what is below, and it seems to work, with the possible exception of the "! -empty". One thing I'm learning (as I go) is that just because something works, doesn't mean it's right or formed correctly...The question I have is how do you determine what requires parentheses and what doesn't in a find command?

In OS X, -and is "implied by the juxtaposition of two expressions it does not have to be specified"

My goal is to have find:
find directories that are over 5 minutes old, not empty, and are not .dot (hidden -i.e. "." and "..")

```
count="$( find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \( ! -iname ".*" \) | wc -l )"
echo $count
if [ "$count" -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo $(date +"%r") "$cust_name loc 9: "${count}" directories exist to process, moving them" >> $logFILE
    find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \( ! -iname ".*" \) | xargs -I % mv % ../02_processing/

    cd $processingPATH

    # append the time and the directories to be processed in files_sent.txt
    date +"---- %a-%b-%d %H:%M ----" >> $filesSENTlog
    ls >> $filesSENTlog

    find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/dcm4che-2.0.28/bin/dcmsnd $aet@$peer:$port
    echo $(date +"%r") "$cust_name loc 10: Processing ${count} items..." >> $logFILE

    # clean up processed studies > from processing to processed
    echo $(date +"%r") "$cust_name loc 11: Moving ${count} items to 03_processed" >> $logFILE
    mv * $processedPATH
else
    echo $(date +"%r") "$cust_name loc 12: there are no directories to process" >> $logFILE
fi
```

could I just do:

```
find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \! -iname ".*"
```

? or is that not correct for some reason?

Comment: So your question boils down to: is `find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \! -iname ".*"` equivalent to `find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \( ! -iname ".*" \)` - right?

Comment: That, and what determines the use of parentheses. What would also help is, what is the proper term for the use of the parentheses specifically in find. I don't really understand it's usage -so I'll search when I can figure out what it's specifically called...  and finally, is it good, bad, or ugly? :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`find` has the following operators listed in order of precedence (highest -> lowest)

1. `()`
2. `!|-not`
3. `-a|-and`
4. `-o|-or`
5. `,` (`GNU` only)

*Note: All `tests` and `actions` have an implied `-a` linking each other*

So if you are not using any operators, you don't have to worry about precedence. If you are just using `not` like in your case, you don't really have to worry about precedence either, since `! exp exp2` will get treated as `(! exp) AND (exp2)` as expected, due to `!` having higher precedence than the implied `and`.

**Example where precedence matters**

```
> mkdir empty && cd empty && touch a && mkdir b
> find -mindepth 1 -type f -name 'a' -or -name 'b'
./a
./b
```

The above got treated as `find -mindepth 1 (-type f AND -name 'a') OR (-name 'b')`

```
> find -mindepth 1 -type f \( -name 'a' -or -name 'b' \)
./a
```

The above got treated as `find -mindepth 1 (-type f) AND ( -name 'a' OR -name 'b')`

*Note: Options ( i.e. -mindepth, -noleaf, etc... ) are always true*

**Conclusion**

The following two uses of `find` are exactly the same

- `find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \( ! -iname ".*" \) | wc -l`
- `find . -type d -mmin +5 \! -empty \! -iname ".*"  | wc -l`

Both get treated as

- `find . (-type d) AND (-mmin +5) AND (! -empty) AND (! -iname ".*") | wc -l`