# Obtain output from a bash command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, command, output

I'm trying to obtain the output of a bash command. More precisely, I need to store the number of lines that contains a string in a file:

```
variable_name = AAAAAAA
PATH_TO_SEARCH = .
COMMAND = "grep -R #{variable_name} #{PATH_TO_SEARCH} | wc -l"
```

To execute the command I tried both methods:

```
num_lines = %x[ #{COMMAND} ]
num_lines = `#{COMMAND}`
```

but the problem is: In "num_lines" I have **1)** the number of lines that contain the string **(OK!)** and **2)** output from grep like "grep: /home/file_example.txt: No such file or directory" **(NO!)**.
I would like to store just the first output.

Comment: Do you mean the first output as the output for the first file only?

Comment: `COMMAND = "grep ... | grep -v '^grep:' | wc -l"`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may just need to suppress the error messages.

"You can use the -s or --no-messages flag to suppress errors." found from [How can I have grep not print out 'No such file or directory' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors)

Comment: More generally, use `&>/dev/null` after the command and it's arguments to supress all output.