# How to get names of all the files (in one directory) contain a certain line of text?

Tags: bash

for example:

I hope to get names of all the files contains

```
start on startup
```

in `/etc/init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below grep command,

```
$ cd /etc/init
$ grep -l "start on startup" *
```

OR

Through a single command,

```
$ grep -l "start on startup" /etc/init/*
```

From `man grep`,

```
-l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following should do the trick:

`grep -ls 'start on startup' /etc/init/*`

This will grep through all files in your `/etc/init` directory and print out only the filenames while also omitting any errors (i.e. `/etc/init/<dir_name> is a directory`).

Here is a post that explains the `-l` option: [grep-show-just-filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-no-in-line-matches-on-linux)

Here is another post that explains the `-s` option: [grep-omit-file/directory-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors)