# Why does grep print out "No such file or directory"?

Tags: macos, grep, find, xargs

I tried to search the MarkDown files containing some specific text under the working directory, so I used the command below:

```
find . -name "*.md"  | xargs grep "interpretation"
```

However, though I got the result what I need, the terminal also print out much errors like below:

```
grep: Problem: No such file or directory
grep: Solving: No such file or directory
grep: with: No such file or directory
grep: Algorithms: No such file or directory
……
etc
```

---

I wrote my solution as a answer below.

Comment: if you want to search files only in current dir without going inside sub-dirs, just use `grep 'interpretation' *.md`... and if you need sub-dir as well, use `-type f` and `-exec` with `find` instead of xargs

Comment: @Sundeep ,Thank you! I have searched the usage about `-exec` and it is convenient! I will update my answer. I am a fresh man on command-line, sorry for that :)

Comment: using command line is never ending experience... you might want to bookmark https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice if you are going to use `find` regularly

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

At first I used the option `-s` to suppress errors, suggested by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors/6426401#6426401), but @Kelvin 's comment reminded me the true reason is that my many files' names has the `spaces`.

So the correct command is:

`$ find . -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "some-text-want-to-find"` (on os x)

Here is some clearer explanation I found:

> Unix-like systems allow embedded `spaces` (and even newlines!) in ﬁlenames. This causes problems for programs like `xargs` that construct argument lists for other programs. An embedded `space` will be treated as a delimiter and the resulting command will interpret each space-separated word as a separate argument. To overcome this, `ﬁnd` and `xarg` allow the optional use of a `null` character as argument separator. A `null` character is deﬁned in ASCII as the character represented by the number zero (as opposed to, for example, the `space` character, which is deﬁned in ASCII as the character represented by the number 32). The ﬁnd command provides the action `-print0`, which produces `null` separated output, and the `xargs` command has the `–null` option, which accepts `null` separated input.

—— *The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction* by William E. Shotts

**Warning**: When you are on os x, the null separated option of `xargs` command is `–0`

---

**Updated 2017-05-27 22:58:48**

Thanks to @Sundeep ,who suggested me to use `-exec`, a new feature in `ﬁnd` itself, rather than `xargs`.

So, use this to search files in current dir and its sub-dirs:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.md" -exec grep "some-text-want-to-find" {} +
```

Note:

[What is meaning of {} + in find's -exec command? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command)

Answer (score 1):

I found that when there's **symbolic link and the destination directory not exist**, it will print out `no such file or directory`