# How to remove system redirect message from screen

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am getting dhcp server status using 
`service dhcpd status`. Result is

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  dhcpd.service
>   ● dhcpd.service - DHCPv4 Server Daemon
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>
> Active: active (running) since......

I just want to extract `active` and send to php (Zend) server. To do it, I used

`service dhcpd status | awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "Active:") {print $(I+1)};}'`

Result is

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  dhcpd.service
>
> active

I just don't understand how to remove **Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  dhcpd.service** part from the result.

I have tried [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors), but they were not addressing my issue.

Am I missing something? or is there a better way to do it? I am not familiar with shell scripts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to replace `service dhcpd status` by `service dhcpd status 2>&1`.

Comment: Instead of `service dhcpd status | awk ...` you should use: `service dhcpd status |& awk ...`

Comment: @Cyrus No, it doesn't give me the result I want. I just want to take `active` and also remove this "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status dhcpd.service"

Comment: @anubhava Yes, worked. Please post it as an answer to accept. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Awk` looking for the `Active:` string and print the status

```
service dhcpd status 2>&1 | awk '$1=="Active:"{print $2}'
```

The part `$1="Active:"` looks up the line whose first column value is `Active:` and print the next column value which is the status you are looking for.

As suggested above, redirect the `stderr`, the standard error stream to stdout and apply `Awk` on it to filter the error message.

---

As suggested by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) in comments you could use `|&` in recent versions of `bash` to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` as

```
service dhcpd status |& awk '$1=="Active:"{print $2}'
```

Comment: Yes, I just want to remove printing "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  dhcpd.service" in terminal

Comment: @Sachith: Refer my update above

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see see your updated answer. Deleted mine and upvoted your's

Comment: original credit goes to you btw @anubhava ;)

Comment: @anubhava was the first to give the correct answer for my problem.